# Wrong composer configuration on a reusable symfony bundle

Tags: symfony, composer-php, autoloader

I created a new bundle available here : 
https://github.com/PHPDreamTeam/pink-flamingo-user-bundle

I want to install it using composer, I created a composer package, I published it on packagist and finally, I can install it, but it fails to load when I do in AppKernel :

`new PHPDreamTeam\PinkFlamingoUserBundle\PinkFlamingoUserBundle()`

This is my error : 

`Attempted to load class "PinkFlamingoUserBundle" from namespace "PinkFlamingoUserBundle".
Did you forget a "use" statement for "PHPDreamTeam\PinkFlamingoUserBundle\PinkFlamingoUserBundle"?`

What's wrong with my project?

Comment: i install the bundle without any errors

Comment: did it worked when you instantiated it in your appKernel 
( `new PHPDreamTeam\PinkFlamingoUserBundle\PinkFlamingoUserBundle()` )

Comment: maybe a cache issue ? I removed the references to the bundle in my ~/.composer/cache/vcs && ~/.composer/cache/repo

Comment: yes, i add to the appKerner and empty the cache successfully (seam you miss some class on the repo as example PinkFlamingoUserBundle\User\ExtraUserInterface referenced in the PHPDreamTeam\PinkFlamingoUserBundle\Entity\User class)

Comment: hi @d3cima have you solved?

Comment: Yes, it was a cache issue, bad config. thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a cache issue, per comment by @matteo under original question.

Comment: @Ajean - incorrect review. The OP posted this answer based on someone's comment that helped solve the issue. Granted, the OP should've asked the commenter to post a formal answer, but... this isn't just a 'thank you' answer (though the 'thanks' part should be edited out, which I just did).